# Simple attribute parser for HTML

Tags: java, performance, html, parsing, state

I am studying Java and trying to write an HTML parser, which should parse tag names and attributes. I wrote a class (code below) using the State pattern.

This is necessary for my training project, where I currently use JSoup. JSoup is too slow for me though, so I want better performance. Although suggestions about following conventions and best practise are also good. Additionally, comments on the interface / API of my class would be appreciated too.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AttributeParser {
    public AttributeParser(BufferedReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
        states.put(AttrStat.NAME, new NameState());
        states.put(AttrStat.VALUE, new ValueState());
        states.put(AttrStat.VALUE_QUOTES, new ValueQuotesState());
        states.put(AttrStat.AFTER_NAME, new AfterNameState());
        states.put(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR, new NewAttrState());
        states.put(AttrStat.NEW_VALUE, new NewValueState());
        current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR);
    }

    public String tag() throws IOException {
        int ch;
        ch = reader.read();
        while (ch > 0) {
            if (ch == '<') {
                StringBuilder tagName = new StringBuilder();
                ch = reader.read();
                while ((ch > 0) && (" >\n\t".indexOf(ch) == -1)) {
                    reader.mark(1);
                    tagName.append((char) ch);
                    if (tagName.toString().equals("!--")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    ch = reader.read();
                }
                if (ch == '>') {
                    reader.reset();
                }
                return tagName.toString();
            }
            ch = reader.read();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> attribute() throws IOException {
        attr = new HashMap<>();
        while (current.read(reader.read())) {
            //without body
        }
        addAttribute();
        return attr;
    }

    private void addAttribute() {
        if ((name.length() > 0) && !name.toString().equals("/") && (attr.get(name.toString()) == null)) {
            attr.put(name.toString(), value.toString());
        }
        name.setLength(0);
        value.setLength(0);
    }

    abstract class State {
        final public boolean read(int ch) {
            if (ch == -1) return false;
            switch (ch) {
                case '>':
                    return readAngleBracket((char) ch);
                case '=':
                    return readEqual((char) ch);
                case '\n':
                case ' ':
                case '\t':
                    return readBreaker((char) ch);
                //double quote
                case '"':
                case '\'':
                    return readSequence((char) ch);
                default:
                    return readChar((char) ch);
            }
        }

        protected abstract boolean readChar(char ch);

        protected abstract boolean readSequence(char ch);

        protected abstract boolean readBreaker(char ch);

        protected abstract boolean readEqual(char ch);

        protected boolean readAngleBracket(char ch) {
            addAttribute();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class NameState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            name.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            name.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            current = states.get(AttrStat.AFTER_NAME);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_VALUE);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class ValueState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            addAttribute();
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class ValueQuotesState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            if (quotes == ch) {
                addAttribute();
                current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR);
            } else {
                value.append(ch);
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readAngleBracket(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class AfterNameState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            addAttribute();
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR);
            name.append(ch);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            addAttribute();
            name.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_ATTR);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NEW_VALUE);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class NewAttrState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            name.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NAME);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            name.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NAME);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            addAttribute();
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            name.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.NAME);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class NewValueState extends State {
        protected boolean readChar(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.VALUE);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readSequence(char ch) {
            quotes = ch;
            current = states.get(AttrStat.VALUE_QUOTES);
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readBreaker(char ch) {
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean readEqual(char ch) {
            value.append(ch);
            current = states.get(AttrStat.VALUE);
            return true;
        }
    }

    enum AttrStat {NAME, VALUE, VALUE_QUOTES, AFTER_NAME, NEW_ATTR, NEW_VALUE}

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
    private State current;
    private char quotes = ' ';
    private HashMap<String, String> attr;
    private HashMap<AttrStat, State> states = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't tell anything about bugs, but add few comments:

1. I think it would be easier for you to develop parsers if you will implement tokenization logic as a separate part.
2. If your parser accepts BufferedReader parameter, you'd better implement Closeable interface and take care of reader inside close method. That will also give you a possibility to use parser as try-with resource.
3. It's better to accept something more common than BufferedReader (abstract Reader for example).

P.S. If you want really fast implementation and it's not crucial for you to implement your own parser then maybe you should try to use StAX.